# Ruby On Rails Active Record - Where Condition AND This Condition or That Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple time tracker and just trying to write a query that satisfies the following and pulls all records with the following: user_id = 6 AND (is_paused is true OR manual_input_hours is nil).

Based on what I tried to structure as follows

```
Timerecord.where(user_id: 6).where(Timerecord.where(is_paused: true).or(Timerecord.where.not(manual_input_hours: 0)))
```

but it doesnt work, getting the following error: Unsupported argument type: #Timerecord::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000056546f549358 (Timerecord::ActiveRecord_Relation) (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the OR part correct, you just need to combine it with the user query. You can do this with the merge method to get the **AND** behaviour:

```rb
records_for_user = Timerecord.where(user_id: 6)
paused           = Timerecord.where(is_paused: true)
has_manual_input = Timerecord.where.not(manual_input_hours: 0)

# records_for_user AND (paused OR has_manual_input)
records_for_user.merge(paused.or(has_manual_input))
```